# MongoDB: почему не работает цепочка методов findById и aggregate?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Из коллекции офферов (offers) хочу найти 1 оффер, по айдишнику.
А затем в этом оффере с помощью метода aggregate заменить в поле hostId айдишник юзера на данные полученные из коллекции users.

```
public async findById(offerId: string): Promise<DocumentType<OfferEntity> | null> {
    return this.offerModel
      .findById(offerId)
      .aggregate([
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: 'users',
            localField: 'hostId',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'user'
          }
        },
        {
          $set: {
            'hostId': '$user'
          }
        }
      ]).exec();
  }
```

Comment: пробовали использовать mongoose.populate()????
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно использовать $match оператор для поиска

```
const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

public async findById(offerId: string): Promise<DocumentType<OfferEntity> | null> {
        return this.offerModel
          .aggregate([
            {
              $match: { _id: ObjectId(offerId) }
            },
            {
              $lookup: {
                from: 'users',
                localField: 'hostId',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'user'
              }
            },
            {
              $set: {
                'hostId': '$user'
              }
            }
          ]).exec();
      }
```

Comment: Понял, сейчас попробую сделать. Пока что-то не получается. TypeScript опять ругается пишет:

"Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'DocumentType<OfferEntity, BeAnObject>'.
  Type 'any[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Document<ObjectId, BeAnObject, OfferEntity>': $assertPopulated, $getAllSubdocs, $ignore, $isDefault, and 49 more.ts(2322)"

Comment: после exec() напишите as DocumentType<OfferEntity> или Promise<DocumentType<OfferEntity>>
попробуйте 2 варианта.
Собственно ошибка в том, что offerModel.aggregate возвращает тип Promise<any>, а вы указываете что ваша функция вернет тип Promise<DocumentType<OfferEntity> | null>

Comment: еще есть вариант написать так: return Promise<DocumentType<OfferEntity>>this.offerModel.aggregate(ваш код

Comment: или: return DocumentType<OfferEntity>this.offerModel.aggregate(ваш код

Comment: сделал как вы написали, но это не помогло, редактор(VS Code) предложил следующую строку: `.exec() as unknown as Promise<DocumentType<OfferEntity>>;`, после этого ошибка пропала.
Но сам метод перестал работать - сделал запрос, получил вместо оффера пустой массив :(

Comment: попробуйте удалить все пайплайны кроме {$match:...} - будет результат? Если ничего не найдет - проверьте чтобы документ с этим айди был в коллекции

Comment: id точно есть в коллекции, я сейчас проверил.
Может быть это связано с тем что offerId обёрнут ObjectId.
У меня появляется ошибка: "Cannot find name 'ObjectId'. Did you mean 'Object'?"
И я вынужден исправить ObjectId на просто Object.
Может ли в этом быть проблема?

Comment: ну так конечно не найдет - если такая ошибка есть. попробуйте такой пайплайн: { $match: { $expr : { $eq: [ '$_id' , { $toObjectId: "61fc458b46d7874a3a97ef79" } ] } } }

Comment: чтобы от прошлой ошибки избавиться и с прошлым пайплайном искать нужно вначале еще сделать: const mongoose = require('mongoose');

Comment: mongoose импортировал в модуль, пайплайн этот добавил: `{ $match: { $expr : { $eq: [ '$_id' , { $toObjectId: offerId } ] } } }` но так вылезла ещё гора ошибок. Этот TypeScript просто жесть :(

Comment: Попробовал импортнуть из mongoose ObjectId:

import { ObjectId } from 'mongoose';
Но и это не помогло. Этот ObjectId почему-то не используется кодом. И редактор предлагает удалить этот импорт, т.к. "'ObjectId' is declared but its value is never read"

Comment: import { ObjectId } from 'mongoose'; нужен с тем пайплайном который я указал в ответе.Если пробуем другой пайплайн - import не нужен

Comment: Сделал следующий импорт: `import mongoose from 'mongoose';`

А в match написал вот так: `$match: { _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(offerId) }`

Теперь всё заработало.
По сути ваш ответ был изначально верным. Проблема была связана с типизацией. Поэтому ваш ответ принимаю. Спасибо большое за помощь, респект от всей души.